# Hover text in table heading cell

Tags: html, semantics, user-experience, abbr

Is there a semantically correct way of showing a tooltip in a table header cell that explains something about the column's data?

My table looks like this:

```
---------------------
| URL   | Pageviews |
---------------------
| url/1 |  5 / 20   |
---------------------
| url/2 |  2 / 14   |
---------------------
```

I want the "Pageviews" text to have a tooltip that says "Week / Total" (explaining why the data looks like that).

Is `abbr` the right element for me to use? (it would look like this: `<th><abbr title="Week / Total">Pageviews</abbr></th>` I can't seem to find a better one. The definition says it's supposed to be used for abbreviations, which is not my case.

Comment: Why not just use the title attribute on the th?

Comment: @j08691 I'd like to style it later, maybe have it (the `abbr` element) show a question mark icon to the right (something like a `padding-right` and a `background` in CSS).

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 allows you to use the "title" attribute on any element.
http://dev.w3.org/html5/alt-techniques/ is a good summary of such techniques.

```
<th title="Week"> Pageviews </th>
```

I'd highly recommend adding a `<caption/>` under the table with such data for usability and UX purposes !